# Django auto-populate on admin load

Tags: python, django

I am building a simple Django project to manage a bunch of phone numbers and call logs that we have in Twilio and other cloud telephony providers. I would like to keep in Django a list of the phone numbers that we have in Twilio. I am easily able to query Twilio's API to get our current numbers, and it seems quite simple to use this list to populate my Django DB.

However, to make sure the list in Django is kept in sync with Twilio, I would like to call Twilio's API and update the list of numbers in Django every time a user loads the list of phone numbers in the admin.

Question: how do I get Django to run this call every time the list of numbers loads in the admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom Django admin class and redefine e.g. [ModelAdmin.get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) to fetch the new data, then return the QuerySet:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        update_data_from_api()
        return = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a custom [admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-as-modeladmin-methods) to the phone list's ModelAdmin for the upload process, and initiate the API fetch there.

Comment: From what I understood, admin actions are supposed to be applied to a number of items selected from the loaded list. Can I initiate an action without any item selected?

Comment: Yes, you can.  It won't complain.

Comment: Tried this but it seems that Django does expect items to be selected: `Items must be selected in order to perform actions on them. No items have been changed.`

Comment: Oh, right.  Apparently I'd overridden that behavior.  I'm using a modified version of django-admin-bootstrapped that prompts for action confirmation with a modal.  Maybe you could make a custom admin view instead.